# How To Find A Member That Register And Deposit At The Same Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i'm a newbie in SQL. I have 2 tables 
Table 1 (TBMember):

```
MemberCode | Date
001        | Jan 21
002        | Jan 21
003        | Jan 21
004        | Jan 21
```

Table 2 (TBDeposit):

```
Date | MemberCode | Deposit
Jan 21 | 001 | $100
Jan 21 | 001 | $200
Jan 21 | 002 | $300
Jan 21 | 002 | $400
Jan 21 | 003 | $500
```

First, i want to find how many member that register on that day. Select Count(membercode) from TBMember where date = 'Jan 21'. This return 4. This one is ok for me.

Second, i want to find how many member that register and deposit on the same day. I want this return 3, because only 3 member that register and deposit at that day. How can i do this in SQL Server?
Thanks

Comment: Do a JOIN on MemberCode and date.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure what is the syntax. Can you show me how? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join

Comment: Have you managed to join the table? When you have, try conditions in the WHERE clause and see what happens. It would be a great idea to add some rows with other dates than the already existing one to your sample data!

Comment: Hi jarlh, i managed to fix it already. Thanks a lot for your help! Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Darren: Ankit Bajpai answer is right. Please try with sample data that you provided below.

```
--Data Setup
Declare @TBMember table(MemberCode varchar(3), MDate varchar(20))
insert into @TBMember
values
('001','Jan 21'),
('002','Jan 21'),
('003','Jan 21'),
('004','Jan 21')

--Table 2 (TBDeposit):
Declare @TBDeposit table(MDate varchar(20), MemberCode varchar(3),Deposit varchar(10))
insert into @TBDeposit 
values
('Jan 21','001','$100'),
('Jan 21','001','$200'),
('Jan 21','002','$300'),
('Jan 21','002','$400'),
('Jan 21','003','$500')

SELECT *
FROM   @TBMember

SELECT *
FROM   @TBDeposit 

--First Question
SELECT Count(membercode) membercount
FROM   @TBMember
WHERE  mdate = 'Jan 21'
--Second Question
SELECT Count(DISTINCT td.membercode) membercount
FROM   @TBMember tm
       INNER JOIN @TBDeposit td
               ON tm.MemberCode = td.MemberCode
                  AND tm.mdate = td.MDate
WHERE  tm.MDate = 'Jan 21'
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution. But the return is still Zero. On my table, the date isn't jus Jan 21 actually. It also contain the time. Is it because of this query (tm.mdate = td.MDate) that it returns zero?

Comment: Hi, already fixed it. It's the date that cause the problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        select count(distinct dp.MemberCode) 
          from TBDeposit dp 
    inner join TBMember mmb 
            on dp.MemberCode = mmb. MemberCode and dp.Date = mmb.Date
```

if you want to limit the date to some specific date you just go with where Date = 'date you want to known'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT M.MemberCode )
FROM TBMember M INNER JOIN TBDeposit D
ON M.MemberCode = D.MemberCode
AND M.Date = D.Date
WHERE M.Date = 'Jan 21'
```